# Two Phase Lookup operator << issue?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I'm trying to port my own code from VS2012 to g++4.8.

I'm getting this compliation error:

```
AllocationManager.cpp: In member function ‘void AllocationManager::printMemoryLeaks()’:
TRLogger.h:247:42: error: ‘streamAggrator’ was not declared in this scope
 #define TRLOG_INFO streamAggrator(logINFO) << PACKET_DESCRIPTION << __FUNCTION__ << ":" << __LINE__ << ": "
                                          ^
AllocationManager.cpp:39:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘TRLOG_INFO’
  TRLOG_INFO << "sdfs\n";
```

Where `printMemoryLeaks` is a dummy function (`AllocationManager` is not templated):

```
void AllocationManager::printMemoryLeaks(void)
 {

    TRLOG_INFO << "sdfs\n"; 
}
```

In the file `TRLogger.h`:

```
enum TLogLevel {logERROR, logWARNING, logINFO, logDEBUG, logDEBUG1, logDEBUG2, logDEBUG3, logDEBUG4};

class streamAggrator
{
public:
    streamAggrator(TLogLevel logLevel);

/* private: */ 
    FILELog fLog;
    WarnLog wlog;
    std::ostringstream& s1; 
    std::ostringstream& s2; 
};


template<typename T>
streamAggrator& operator<<(streamAggrator& agg, const T& obj) 
{
    agg.s1 << obj;
    agg.s2 << obj;
    agg.s2.flush();
    return agg; 
}
```

....

```
#define TRLOG_INFO streamAggrator(logINFO) << PACKET_DESCRIPTION << __FUNCTION__ << ":" << __LINE__ << ": "
```

How can I solve this function - I didn't find any place that I can use `this` or `using` to help the compiler.

Thanks,
Guy

Comment: don't worry about the #includes - since it found TRLOG_WARN

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) if possible; especially the context of the function `void AllocationManager::printMemoryLeaks()` is of interest.

Comment: What's at `AllocationManager::printMemoryLeaks()`? Is that where line 247 is at? Can you show that in your code above?

Comment: *If* there is a lookup issue (other than the binding of reference Dietmar already points out), you are not showing enough information to be able to resolve it. The title is probably a red herring… is `AllocationManager::printMemoryLeaks` a template? if not, there won't be two phase lookup at all and you are barking at the wrong tree here..

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I mentioned it explictly that it is not a template - but you're right about the two phase - that was my guess which has proven to be wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that you try to pass a temporary `streamAggrator` object to a function which takes a `streamAggrator` by non-`const` reference. You can't bind temporary object to non-`const` references. The work-around for this problem is to make the output operator member of your `streamAggrator`: while you cannot bind a temporary to a non-`const` reference, you *can* call non-`const` member functions. Note that you'll also get problems with maniputors like `std::flush` (the issue there is that these are templates themselves and you actually need to a concrete operator to call them with to have the compiler deduce their template arguments).

Clearly, I would solve the problem properly, i.e., instead of trying to dig about an attempt to a solution which doesn't create a stream, I would create a `std::streambuf` do do the actual work. Your examples doesn't do anything useful, i.e., I can't really tell what you are trying to do but the code looks remarkably like trying to do something like `teestream`: write once but send the output to multiple destintations. I have posted corresponding stream buffers quite a few times in the post (mostly on Usenet, though, but I think, at least, once on Stackoverflow, too).

Although I don't know how to get rid of the macro to fill in the `__FILE__` and the `__LINE__`, the actual stream formatting should probably use a stream buffer:

```
struct teebuf: std::streambuf {
private:
    std::streambuf* sb1;
    std::streambuf* sb2;
public:
    teebuf(std::streambuf* sb1, std::streambuf* sb2): sb1(sb1), sb2(sb2) {}
    int overflow(int c) {
        this->sb1->sputc(c);
        this->sb2->sputc(c);
        return std::char_traits<char>::not_eof(c);
    }
    int sync() {
        this->sb1->pubsync();
        this->sb2->pubsync();
    }
};
class logstream
    : std::ostream {
    std::ofstream out;
    teebuf        sbuf;
public:
    logstream()
        : out("file.log")
        , sbuf(out.rdbuf(), std::clog.rdbuf()) {
        this->init(&this->sbuf);
    }
    logstream(logstream&& other)
        : out(std::move(other.out))
        , sbuf(std::move(other.sbuf)) {
        this->init(&this->sbuf);
};
```

I *think* you can return the log stream. I don't know what your logging level is meant to do but I guess its processing was removed while preparing the question: it is probably necessary to change the implementation to take the logging level suitably into account.

Comment: Thx, "You can't bind temporary object to non-const references" - What's the reason behind it?

Comment: @GuyL: In general, something is add if you try to change temporaries. The reasoning is explained, e.g., in Bjarne's "Design and Evolution of C++". I don't really buy into entirely and think that `const` was an early attempt at what is properly addressed with rvalue references.
Since you have tagged your question C++11 I'll post a sketch of how I would do it (it requires some C++11 functionality, though, to return streams).

Comment: So, why there is `T&&` and `const T&&` if a r-value cannot be changed?

Comment: and also
`#define TRLOG_INFO { streamAggrator __s(logINFO);  __s << PACKET_DESCRIPTION << __FUNCTION__ << ":" << __LINE__ << ": "; }`
is not working :/

Comment: @GuyL: I didn't say that rvalues can't be changed! In fact rvalues _can_ be changed but they can't be bound to a `T&`. Of course, a `T const&&` can't be changed.

Comment: @GuyL: yes, you need to use a temporary in some form. However, you need to make sure that the first thing you call on it is a member function. For example, you can use `std::ostringstream() << "hello";` because the used output operator, `std::ostream& std::istream::operator(char const*)` is a member function which actually does return a reference!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43194/discussion-between-guy-l-and-dietmar-kuhl)

Comment: He could just make the parameter a `const StreamAggregator&`.  The `streams` held by reference will still be non-const.

Comment: @BenVoigt: sure, except that the result looks stream-like but isn't a stream and won't work, at least, with some manipulators. Another fix is also mentioned above: he could make the template operator a member function which would share the same problems, however.